# Wookmark jQuery plugin wordpress : is there a conflict

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I try to install [Wookmark jQuery plugin](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin) on my wordpress site running under Responsive theme. It works when I run script from a page I create outside wordpress...

But when I try to run the plugin inside a wordpress page : nothing appen.Do i miss something when I call the scripts is there a conflict with calling two times jQuery ??

I have this in my page

```
<!-- include jQuery -->
  <script src="wookjs/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>


  <!-- Include the plug-in -->
  <script src="wookjs/jquery.wookmark.js"></script>
```

Comment: Check your browser console for any errors. Of course you should not include jQuery twice.

Comment: You should be using [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to load jQuery and other javascript sources to help prevent conflicts.

Comment: thanks I will do that it seem more secure way that what I do. And finally it works under wordpress